# Where do DICOM files store inversion time?

Tags: biomedical-engineering

I'm trying to write a T1 Mapping program in Python but I am having a hard time finding the inversion times in the DICOM files I downloaded from [visible human project](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/visible/visible_human.html) on the NIH website.

When I printed out all the meta information I saw the huge list below. Very informative but there are no inversion times anywhere! Are they labeled differently? The website doesn't seem to have any kind of explanation of how data is stored.

```
Dir Name: DICOM
Dataset.file_meta -------------------------------
(0002, 0000) File Meta Information Group Length  UL: 162
(0002, 0001) File Meta Information Version       OB: b'\x00\x01'
(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: MR Image Storage
(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017994663.236098
(0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: Explicit VR Little Endian
(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13
-------------------------------------------------
(0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 864
(0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 138042
(0008, 0005) Specific Character Set              CS: 'ISO_IR 100'
(0008, 0008) Image Type                          CS: ['ORIGINAL', 'PRIMARY', 'OTHER']
(0008, 0010) Recognition Code                    LO: 'ACR-NEMA 1.0'
(0008, 0016) SOP Class UID                       UI: MR Image Storage
(0008, 0018) SOP Instance UID                    UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017994663.236098
(0008, 0020) Study Date                          DA: '20020404'
(0008, 0021) Series Date                         DA: '20020404'
(0008, 0022) Acquisition Date                    DA: '20020404'
(0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20020404'
(0008, 0030) Study Time                          TM: '174525.000000'
(0008, 0031) Series Time                         TM: '183108.520000'
(0008, 0032) Acquisition Time                    TM: '183108.520000'
(0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '183108.520000'
(0008, 0040) Data Set Type                       US: 0
(0008, 0041) Data Set Subtype                    LO: 'SE/M'
(0008, 0050) Accession Number                    SH: ''
(0008, 0060) Modality                            CS: 'MR'
(0008, 0070) Manufacturer                        LO: 'Philips Medical Systems'
(0008, 0080) Institution Name                    LO: 'UMC UTRECHT MR 3'
(0008, 0090) Referring Physician's Name          PN: ''
(0008, 1010) Station Name                        SH: 'NTMR3'
(0008, 1030) Study Description                   LO: 'HEAD'
(0008, 1090) Manufacturer's Model Name           LO: 'Gyroscan NT Intera'
(0008, 1140)  Referenced Image Sequence  3 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 104
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 92
   (0008, 1150) Referenced SOP Class UID            UI: MR Image Storage
   (0008, 1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID         UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017988800.561427
   ---------
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 104
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 92
   (0008, 1150) Referenced SOP Class UID            UI: MR Image Storage
   (0008, 1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID         UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017988795.184748
   ---------
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 104
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 92
   (0008, 1150) Referenced SOP Class UID            UI: MR Image Storage
   (0008, 1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID         UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017988795.330609
   ---------
(0009, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 304
(0009, 0010) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI Release 1'
(0009, 0011) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR'
(0009, 0012) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P Release 1'
(0009, 0021) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART 12'
(0009, 1008) [Unknown]                           LO: 'M'
(0009, 1015) [UID]                               LO: '001P01MR012002040511070451'
(0009, 1110) [SPI Release]                       LO: 'T-J1'
(0009, 1112) [Unknown]                           LO: '20010419'
(0009, 1215) [Unique Identifier]                 LO: 'P03100003000508407112002040510174739'
(0009, 1216) [Unknown]                           LO: 'P03100003000508407112002040510174739'
(0009, 1218) [Unknown]                           LO: 'P03100003000508407112002040510174739'
(0009, 2110) [Unknown]                           US: 0
(0010, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 130
(0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: 'HARVARD02'
(0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '20020404'
(0010, 0030) Patient's Birth Date                DA: '19121212'
(0010, 0040) Patient's Sex                       CS: 'M'
(0010, 1030) Patient's Weight                    DS: "15.0"
(0010, 21b0) Additional Patient History          LT: 'PROF.HILLEN/CB/GB'
(0010, 4000) Patient Comments                    LT: 'PROF.HILLEN/CB/GB'
(0018, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 436
(0018, 0020) Scanning Sequence                   CS: 'SE'
(0018, 0021) Sequence Variant                    CS: 'OTHER'
(0018, 0022) Scan Options                        CS: 'FC'
(0018, 0023) MR Acquisition Type                 CS: '2D'
(0018, 0050) Slice Thickness                     DS: "3.0"
(0018, 0080) Repetition Time                     DS: "519.4"
(0018, 0081) Echo Time                           DS: "15.0"
(0018, 0083) Number of Averages                  DS: "2.0"
(0018, 0084) Imaging Frequency                   DS: "63.8971"
(0018, 0085) Imaged Nucleus                      SH: '1H'
(0018, 0086) Echo Number(s)                      IS: "1"
(0018, 0087) Magnetic Field Strength             DS: "1.5"
(0018, 0088) Spacing Between Slices              DS: "3.0"
(0018, 0089) Number of Phase Encoding Steps      IS: "256"
(0018, 0091) Echo Train Length                   IS: "0"
(0018, 0093) Percent Sampling                    DS: "100.0"
(0018, 0094) Percent Phase Field of View         DS: "79.6875"
(0018, 1000) Device Serial Number                LO: '05027'
(0018, 1020) Software Versions                   LO: 'NT 8.1.1'
(0018, 1030) Protocol Name                       LO: 'T1 SE     TR'
(0018, 1081) Low R-R Value                       IS: "0"
(0018, 1082) High R-R Value                      IS: "0"
(0018, 1083) Intervals Acquired                  IS: "0"
(0018, 1084) Intervals Rejected                  IS: "0"
(0018, 1088) Heart Rate                          IS: "0"
(0018, 1250) Receive Coil Name                   SH: 'Head'
(0018, 1251) Transmit Coil Name                  SH: 'B'
(0018, 1312) In-plane Phase Encoding Direction   CS: 'ROW'
(0018, 1314) Flip Angle                          DS: "90.0"
(0018, 4000) Acquisition Comments                LO: 'SPINE      T1 SE     TR'
(0018, 5100) Patient Position                    CS: 'HFS'
(0019, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 2382
(0019, 0010) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART'
(0019, 0011) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART'
(0019, 0012) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/LAST'
(0019, 0015) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART 6'
(0019, 0016) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART 7'
(0019, 001d) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1'
(0019, 0040) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR SPECTRO;1'
(0019, 1000) [Field of View]                     DS: [240.000000, 191.250000]
(0019, 1001) [Stack Type]                        DS: "-4.675011"
(0019, 1002) [Unknown]                           DS: "-20.30716"
(0019, 1003) [Unknown]                           DS: "-91.31184"
(0019, 1005) [CC Angulation]                     DS: "-2.498164"
(0019, 1006) [AP Angulation]                     DS: "-2.738782"
(0019, 1007) [LR Angulation]                     DS: "-0.156173"
(0019, 1008) [Patient Orientation 1]             IS: "1"
(0019, 1009) [Patient Orientation]               IS: "1"
(0019, 100a) [Slice Orientation]                 IS: "1"
(0019, 100f) [Number of Slices]                  IS: "80"
(0019, 1010) [Slice Factor]                      DS: "1.0"
(0019, 1014) [Unknown]                           CS: 'U'
(0019, 1015) [Dynamic Study]                     IS: "0"
(0019, 101a) [FFE Flip Angle]                    DS: "90.0"
(0019, 101b) [Number of Scans]                   IS: "1"
(0019, 101c) [Unknown]                           LO: 'SPINE'
(0019, 101d) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 101e) [Unknown]                           LO: '15'
(0019, 1022) [Dynamic Scan Time Begin]           DS: "0.0"
(0019, 1024) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 1040) [Unknown]                           US: 1
(0019, 1050) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 1067) [Unknown]                           DS: "79.6875"
(0019, 1069) [Number of Phases]                  IS: "1"
(0019, 106a) [Cardiac Frequency]                 IS: "0"
(0019, 106e) [Trigger Delay Time]                DS: "0.0"
(0019, 1070) [Unknown]                           DS: [519.400000, 0.000000]
(0019, 1080) [Number of Chemical Shifts]         IS: "0"
(0019, 1081) [Chemical Shift]                    DS: "0.0"
(0019, 108a) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 108b) [Unknown]                           LO: 'Y'
(0019, 108c) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 108d) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 108e) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 108f) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 1094) [Magnetization Transfer Contrast]   LO: 'N'
(0019, 1095) [Spectral Presaturation With Invers LO: 'N'
(0019, 1096) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 1097) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10a0) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 10a1) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.0"
(0019, 10a3) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.0"
(0019, 10b4) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.156352"
(0019, 10b5) [Unknown]                           DS: "2.738772"
(0019, 10b6) [Unknown]                           DS: "-2.505635"
(0019, 10c9) [Foldover Direction Transverse]     IS: "3"
(0019, 10ca) [Foldover Direction Sagittal]       IS: "0"
(0019, 10cb) [Foldover Direction Coronal]        IS: "0"
(0019, 10cc) [Unknown]                           IS: "3"
(0019, 10cf) [Number of Echoes]                  IS: "1"
(0019, 10d0) [Scan Resolution]                   IS: "256"
(0019, 10d1) [Unknown]                           US: 1
(0019, 10d2) [Water Fat Shift]                   LO: ['', '1.768590E+00']
(0019, 10d3) [Unknown]                           DS: "1.76859"
(0019, 10d5) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 10d6) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 10d7) [Scan Percentage]                   DS: "100.0"
(0019, 10d8) [Halfscan]                          IS: "0"
(0019, 10d9) [EPI Factor]                        IS: "1"
(0019, 10da) [Turbo Factor]                      IS: "0"
(0019, 10db) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 10e0) [Percentage of Scan Completed]      IS: "100"
(0019, 10e1) [Prepulse Delay]                    IS: "0"
(0019, 10f0) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 10f6) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10f7) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10f8) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10f9) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10fa) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10fb) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0019, 10fc) [Resonance Frequency]               LO: 'N'
(0019, 1100) [Field of View]                     IS: "1"
(0019, 1101) [Stack Type]                        IS: "0"
(0019, 1102) [Unknown]                           IS: Array of 40 elements
(0019, 110b) [LR Offcenter]                      DS: "4.675011"
(0019, 110c) [CC Offcenter]                      DS: "-91.31184"
(0019, 110d) [AP Offcenter]                      DS: "20.30716"
(0019, 1121) [Unknown]                           DS: "3.0"
(0019, 1123) [Unknown]                           DS: [2.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000]
(0019, 1124) [Unknown]                           DS: [1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000]
(0019, 1125) [Unknown]                           DS: [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000]
(0019, 1126) [Unknown]                           DS: [1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000]
(0019, 1127) [Unknown]                           DS: [1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000]
(0019, 1128) [Unknown]                           LO: ['M', 'M', 'M']
(0019, 1129) [Unknown]                           DS: [1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000]
(0019, 1130) [Unknown]                           LO: ['SE', 'FFE', 'FFE']
(0019, 1131) [Unknown]                           DS: [9.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000]
(0019, 1150) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.156352"
(0019, 1151) [Unknown]                           DS: "2.738772"
(0019, 1152) [Unknown]                           DS: "-2.505635"
(0019, 1153) [Unknown]                           IS: "80"
(0019, 1154) [Unknown]                           DS: "-0.876311"
(0019, 1155) [Unknown]                           DS: "-20.52385"
(0019, 1156) [Unknown]                           DS: "-11.90295"
(0019, 1157) [Unknown]                           US: 0
(0019, 1158) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.0"
(0019, 1159) [Unknown]                           US: 1
(0019, 1160) [Unknown]                           DS: "191.25"
(0019, 1161) [Unknown]                           DS: "240.0"
(0019, 1162) [Unknown]                           DS: "240.0"
(0019, 1163) [Unknown]                           DS: "3.0"
(0019, 1164) [Repetition Time SE]                IS: "1"
(0019, 1166) [Unknown]                           US: 2
(0019, 1209) [Main Magnetic Field]               DS: "1.5"
(0019, 120e) [Flow Compensation]                 IS: "1"
(0019, 12b1) [Minimum RR Interval]               IS: "0"
(0019, 12b2) [Maximum RR Interval]               IS: "0"
(0019, 12b3) [Number of Rejections]              IS: "0"
(0019, 12b4) [Number of RR Intervals]            IS: Array of 102 elements
(0019, 12b5) [Arrhythmia Rejection]              IS: "0"
(0019, 12b7) [Unknown]                           IS: "102"
(0019, 12c6) [Cycled Multiple Slice]             IS: "0"
(0019, 12ce) [REST]                              IS: "0"
(0019, 12d5) [Unknown]                           DS: "853.8936"
(0019, 12d6) [Fourier Interpolation]             IS: "0"
(0019, 12d9) [Unknown]                           IS: Array of 36 elements
(0019, 12e0) [Prepulse]                          IS: "0"
(0019, 12e1) [Prepulse Delay]                    DS: "0.0"
(0019, 12e2) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 12e3) [Unknown]                           DS: [0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000]
(0019, 12e4) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 12e5) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.0"
(0019, 12f2) [WS Protocol String 3]              LT: 'compose'
(0019, 12f3) [WS Protocol String 4]              LT: 'compose'
(0019, 1510) [Unknown]                           IS: "-1"
(0019, 1600) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0019, 1d31) [Unknown]                           LO: 'SE'
(0019, 4032) [Unknown]                           US: 0
(0020, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 404
(0020, 000d) Study Instance UID                  UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017988797.345169
(0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.1017988905.264309
(0020, 0010) Study ID                            SH: '282779804'
(0020, 0011) Series Number                       IS: "401"
(0020, 0012) Acquisition Number                  IS: "4"
(0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: "14"
(0020, 0030) Image Position                      DS: None
(0020, 0032) Image Position (Patient)            DS: [-129.663470, -134.962203, -85.645619]
(0020, 0035) Image Orientation                   DS: None
(0020, 0037) Image Orientation (Patient)         DS: [0.997903, -0.043587, -0.047856, 0.043668, 0.999046, 0.000637]
(0020, 0050) Location                            DS: None
(0020, 0052) Frame of Reference UID              UI: 1.3.46.670589.5.2.13.2157699395.75405980
(0020, 0060) Laterality                          CS: ''
(0020, 0100) Temporal Position Identifier        IS: "1"
(0020, 0105) Number of Temporal Positions        IS: "1"
(0020, 1040) Position Reference Indicator        LO: ''
(0020, 3402) Modified Image ID                   LO: ''
(0020, 3403) Modified Image Date                 DA: ''
(0020, 3405) Modified Image Time                 TM: ''
(0021, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 332
(0021, 0010) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART'
(0021, 0011) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART'
(0021, 0012) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/LAST'
(0021, 0018) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_CDS Release 1'
(0021, 1000) [Scan Date]                         IS: "1"
(0021, 1006) [Unknown]                           UI: ['', '', '']
(0021, 1008) [Unknown]                           LO: 'PIXEL'
(0021, 1009) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0021, 100a) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0021, 100f) [Unknown]                           CS: 'SE'
(0021, 1010) [Image Type]                        IS: "2"
(0021, 1013) [Unknown]                           LO: 'N'
(0021, 1015) [Unknown]                           US: 0
(0021, 1020) [Slice Number]                      IS: "14"
(0021, 1030) [Echo Number]                       IS: "1"
(0021, 1031) [Patient Reference ID]              DS: "75405980.0"
(0021, 1035) [Chemical Shift Number]             IS: "0"
(0021, 1040) [Phase Number]                      IS: "1"
(0021, 1050) [Dynamic Scan Number]               IS: "1"
(0021, 1100) [Scan Date]                         DA: '20020404'
(0021, 1110) [Image Type]                        TM: '183108.520000'
(0021, 1221) [Slice Gap]                         DS: "0.0"
(0021, 1840) [Unknown]                           IS: "4"
(0028, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 198
(0028, 0002) Samples per Pixel                   US: 1
(0028, 0004) Photometric Interpretation          CS: 'MONOCHROME2'
(0028, 0010) Rows                                US: 256
(0028, 0011) Columns                             US: 256
(0028, 0030) Pixel Spacing                       DS: [0.937500, 0.937500]
(0028, 0100) Bits Allocated                      US: 16
(0028, 0101) Bits Stored                         US: 12
(0028, 0102) High Bit                            US: 11
(0028, 0103) Pixel Representation                US: 0
(0028, 1050) Window Center                       DS: "2035.0"
(0028, 1051) Window Width                        DS: "4071.0"
(0028, 1052) Rescale Intercept                   DS: "0.0"
(0028, 1053) Rescale Slope                       DS: "5.850549"
(0028, 1054) Rescale Type                        LO: 'US'
(0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 1784
(0029, 0010) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/PART'
(0029, 0011) Private tag data                    LO: 'PHILIPS MR/LAST'
(0029, 001b) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_CDS Release 1'
(0029, 0020) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1'
(0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;5'
(0029, 1004) [Unknown]                           US: 1
(0029, 1020) [Unknown]                           LO: 'normalized'
(0029, 1031) [Unknown]                           DS: [1.000000, 1.000000]
(0029, 1032) [Unknown]                           DS: [0.000000, 0.000000]
(0029, 1050) [Unknown]                           DS: "2035.0"
(0029, 1051) [Unknown]                           DS: "4071.0"
(0029, 1052) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.0"
(0029, 1053) [Unknown]                           DS: "0.004875"
(0029, 1110) [FP Min]                            DS: "0.0"
(0029, 1120) [FP Max]                            DS: "175655.9"
(0029, 1161) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0029, 1162) [Unknown]                           IS: "0"
(0029, 1183) [View Transform]                    IS: "0"
(0029, 1b10) [Unknown]                           OB: Array of 316 elements
(0029, 200f)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 216
   (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 204
   (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
   (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 13
   (0029, 25cd)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
      (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
      (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 110
      (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 98
      (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
      (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 14
      (0029, 2505) [Unknown]                           FL: 0.0
      (0029, 2506) [Unknown]                           FL: 4095.0
      (0029, 2520) [Unknown]                           FL: -0.0020869856234639883
      (0029, 2521) [Unknown]                           FL: 16.990150451660156
      ---------
   ---------
(0029, 201b)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 184
   (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 172
   (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
   (0029, 0026) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;2'
   (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 20
   (0029, 2600) [Unknown]                           FD: 1.0
   (0029, 2601) [Unknown]                           FD: 0.5
   (0029, 2602) [Unknown]                           FD: 0.5
   (0029, 2603) [Unknown]                           SL: 0
   (0029, 2604) [Unknown]                           SL: 1
   (0029, 2605) [Unknown]                           SL: 0
   ---------
(0029, 201c)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 216
   (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 204
   (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
   (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 13
   (0029, 25cd)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
      (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
      (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 110
      (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 98
      (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
      (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 14
      (0029, 2505) [Unknown]                           FL: 0.0
      (0029, 2506) [Unknown]                           FL: 4095.0
      (0029, 2520) [Unknown]                           FL: -0.0020869856234639883
      (0029, 2521) [Unknown]                           FL: 16.990150451660156
      ---------
   ---------
(0029, 2021)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 80
   (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 68
   (0029, 0024) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1'
   (0029, 2468) [Unknown]                           US: 0
   (0029, 246a) [Unknown]                           LO: 'GCOM'
   (0029, 246b) [Unknown]                           US: 0
   ---------
(0029, 204c)  [Unknown]  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 12
   (0008, 0001) Length to End                       UL: 112
   (0029, 0000) Private Creator                     UL: 100
   (0029, 0025) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;1'
   (0029, 0028) Private tag data                    LO: 'SPI-P-Private_ICS Release 1;4'
   (0029, 2500) [Unknown]                           SL: 80
   (0029, 28e0)  [Unknown]  0 item(s) ---- 
   ---------
(0029, 2067) [Unknown]                           LO: 'gcom_NTMR3'
(0029, 2550) [Unknown]                           CS: 'CREATED'
(0029, 2555) [Unknown]                           CS: 'CREATED'
(4008, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 16
(4008, 0212) Interpretation Status ID            CS: 'CREATED'
(7fe0, 0000) Group Length                        UL: 131084
(7fe0, 0010) Pixel Data                          OW: Array of 131072 elementsI'm trying to write a T1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this of direct to help to your problem, but I've just faced something similar for data in my lab that was created with a custom Inversion Recovery Turbo Field Echo sequence instead of standard IR sequence.

For these images, the inversion times were stored in the private field (2001,102b) instead of the [standard (0018,0082)](https://dicom.innolitics.com/ciods/mr-image/mr-image/00180082) .